# What actually means "value" in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el, javabeans

I have read JSP recently, and have a doubt in the javabeans technolgy it uses. Lets say that the following JavaBeans code :

```
package mortgage;
public class Mortgage
{
    private double amount = -1.0;
    public void setAmount(double amount)
    {
         this.amount = amount;
    }
}
```

And lets say i have to make use of this JavaBeans in my JSP and take the parameter values obtain from the HTML form or from the URL query string and JSP code as follows:

```
<jsp:useBean id="calc" class="mortgage.Mortgage" />
<p> Testing . . . 
  <c:set target="${calc}" property="amount"  value="${param.mortgageAmount}" />
   . . . . .
```

This example was little modified from my book. My question is what does this `value` in the above code JSP does? Where does the `mortgageAmount` came from?(is this the value from the HTML form element?)
And also what does `target` and `property` does?

Since I am a novice, i dont know what actually is going on the above code. Please help me and correct me if am wrong?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info (those kind of pages are available by putting your mouse above the tags below the question until you see a popbox and then click *info* link on the popbox).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`value` represents expression that would be set to the `target`

> Where does the mortgageAmount came from?

it assumed to be coming as param as you have used it in your code by `param.mortgageAmount` in url like

```
yourapp/page.jsp?mortgageAmount=someVAlue
```

---

**In Simlper words**

value   is  and Expression to be evaluated which will be set to 
`target` object's property represented by `property`

---

**See Also**

- [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/set.html)

Comment: So as you have mentioned in the above simple example, the `someVAlue` will be assigned to the target `calc` with the property `amount` . Am i Correct?

Comment: Exactly. <!----------------->

Answer (score 1):

`param` is a JSP implicit object. It's a map whose entries are the page parameters - so anything that's come in as a parameter in the query string, or (i think) through a form post.

`Target` and `property` govern what the `c:set` does; it sets the named property on the named target object to the given value.